# PHP defined() why is it returns false, even if the constant is defined?

Tags: php

I can't understand why this code is executed is not the way I want.

```
define('TEST', 123);
echo TEST;
echo "\n";
var_dump( defined(TEST) );
```

print:

```
123
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The short answer is; **Add quotation marks**

Because you're not referring to the constant named `TEST` - you're referring to whatever `TEST` contains.

Wrapped out, this is what you're doing (the code is right - there is no `123` constant):

```
define('TEST', 123);

var_dump( defined(TEST) ); // turns into the below statement
var_dump( defined(123) ); // false - no 123 constant
```

Refer to the constant name instead (enclose it in quotes):

```
define('TEST', 123);

var_dump( defined('TEST') ); // true, the TEST constant is indeed defined
//                ^    ^ Quotation marks are important!
```

**What if my constant is in a namespace?**

If your constant is defined in a namespace, you must include it in the constant name.

```php
namespace Some\Namespace;

const MY_CONST = 'value';

var_dump( defined('MY_CONST') ); // false unless another constant has been defined
var_dump( defined('Some\Namespace\MY_CONST'); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably because defined() require a string as parameter.

```
var_dump( defined('TEST') );
```

Comment: Not entirely true. If you try `defined(TEST)` and the constant *is not* defined, you'll get an `E_NOTICE`, but it'll convert it to the string `TEST`, so if it *isn't* defined, it's the same as saying `defined('TEST')`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo [According to the php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) "bool defined ( string $name )" and "Returns TRUE if the named constant given by name has been defined, FALSE otherwise."

Answer (score 3):

use have call it wrong

```
define('TEST', 123);
echo TEST;
echo "\n";
var_dump( defined(TEST) );//provide The constant name you are providing 123 so it not defined
//correct call would be
var_dump( defined('TEST') );
```